# Compare array element previous and next

Tags: javascript

This seems super basic, but I'm drawing a blank.

I have a couple for loops, and I want to check the `i` and `j` values `-1` and `+1` but obviously as the array I'm checking doesn't have a `arr[0-1]` element, it returns an error. How would I fix that?

```
var islandPerimeter = function(grid) {
let result = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
        if(grid[i][j] === 1) {
            if(grid[i-1][j] !== 1) { //left
                result += 1;
            }
            if(grid[i+1][j] !== 1) { //right
                result += 1;
            }
            if(grid[i][j+1] !== 1) { //bottom
                result += 1;
            }
            if(grid[i][j-1] !== 1) { //top
                result += 1;
            }
        }
      }  
   }
   return result;
};
```

so where I have the `//left` comment I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

How can I best prevent this issue? Thank you.

Here is problem description and `input` and expected `output`:

> You are given a map in form of a two-dimensional integer grid where 1 represents land and 0 represents water.
>
> Grid cells are connected horizontally/vertically (not diagonally). The grid is completely surrounded by water, and there is exactly one island (i.e., one or more connected land cells).
>
> The island doesn't have "lakes" (water inside that isn't connected to the water around the island). One cell is a square with side length 1. The grid is rectangular, width and height don't exceed 100. Determine the perimeter of the island.

```
Input:
[[0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,1,0],
 [0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,0,0]]

Output: 16
```

Comment: Check if the element exists first before trying to access the `[j]` property?

Comment: @CertainPerformance but if it doesn't exist I still want to enter the `if` statement if possible...

Comment: Please can you show the input and ouput?

Comment: According to your code you if won't fire if `grid[i]` doesn't exist

Comment: Like CertainPerformance said, you could do something like `if (grid[i - 1] && grid[i - 1][j] !== 1)` (assuming values aren't falsey).

Comment: @ScottRudiger but the point of doing `!== 1` is because I want to enter the if statement if it doesn't exist or if the value is something other than `-1`...

Comment: Which `if` statement you are talking about. The outer one or all the nested ones?

Comment: @MaheerAli The `if(grid[i-1][j] !== 1) { //left` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following line as condition

```
!grid[i-1] || grid[i-1][j] !== 1
```

This will check if `grid[i-1]` doesnot exists it will jump in the `if` statement. If it exists it will check the other condition normal way.

```
for(var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
        if(grid[i][j] === 1) {
            if(!grid[i-1] || grid[i-1][j] !== 1) { //left
                result += 1;
            }
            if(grid[i+1][j] !== 1) { //right
                result += 1;
            }
            if(grid[i][j+1] !== 1) { //bottom
                result += 1;
            }
            if(grid[i][j-1] !== 1) { //top
                result += 1;
            }
        }
      }  
   }
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
var islandPerimeter = function(grid) {
let result = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
    if(grid[i][j] === 1) {
    if (i > 0) {    
    if(grid[i-1][j] !== 1) { //left
            result += 1;
        }
     }
        if(grid[i+1][j] !== 1) { //right
            result += 1;
        }
        if(grid[i][j+1] !== 1) { //bottom
            result += 1;
        }
        if(grid[i][j-1] !== 1) { //top
            result += 1;
        }
    }
  }  
 }
  return result;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

An initial problem is going to be that on the first pass you're attempting to access `grid[i-1]`. Which, when `i` equals `0`, `grid[-1]` does not exist. With that in mind, some basic validation will ensure only defined cells are checked.

Then you simply need to use the bracket notation to access a property, using the desired value.

```js
var islandPerimeter = function(grid) {
  let result = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
      if(grid[i][j] === 1) {
        if(grid[i-1] && grid[i-1][j] !== 1) { //left
          result += 1;
        }

        if(grid[i+1] && grid[i+1][j] !== 1) { //right
          result += 1;
        }

        if(grid[i][j+1] && grid[i][j+1] !== 1) { //bottom
          result += 1;
        }

        if(grid[i][j-1] && grid[i][j-1] !== 1) { //top
          result += 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};

var grid = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
];

console.log(islandPerimeter(grid)); // returns 5 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```